# how to use loop for array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a array which it reads its cells from a xml file,i wrote it by "for" but now because i don't know how many node i have  i wanna to write this loop in a way that it start and finish up to end of xml file.my code with for is:

```
$description=array();

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
$description[$i]=read_xml_node("dscription",$i);
}
```

and my xml file:

```
<eth0>
<description>WAN</description>      
</eth0>
<eth1>
<description>LAN</description>      
</eth1>
```

in this code i must know "2",but i wanna to know a way that doesn't need to know "2".

Comment: What XML parser/API are you using?

Comment: This is pretty trivial using SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: First of all, there's no native function in PHP called `read_xml_node` so you have to show us either the code of it or the library in which the function exists. Secondly, you spelled `description` wrong (`dscription`).

Comment: DOM,i use my function to read it, my code works correctly,my problem is:if i don't know how many description are in my xml that for will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what kind of parser you are using, but it is very easy with simplexml, so i put together some sample code using simplexml.

something like this should do the trick:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<node>
<eth0>
<description>WAN</description>      
</eth0>
<eth1>
<description>LAN</description>      
</eth1>
</node>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xml as $xmlnode) {
 foreach ($xmlnode as $description) {
  echo $description . " ";
 }
}
```

output:

```
WAN LAN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = count($description);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  print $description[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser you use might allow you to use a `while` loop which will return `false` when it has reached the end of the XML document. For example:

```
while ($node = $xml->read_next_node($mydoc)) {
    //Do whatever...
}
```

If none exists, you can try using `count()` as the second parameter of your `for` loop. It returns the length of an array you specify. For example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {
    //Do whatever...
}
```